# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

im getting this error after data binding the _id property. can anyone help me out.

**CODE:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="iphoneService.selectedIphone._id">
</div>
```

Here IS THE iphone.Service Code

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

import { Iphone } from "./iphone.model";

@Injectable()
export class IphoneService {
  selectedIphone: Iphone;
  iphones: Iphone[];
  readonly baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/iphone";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  postIphone(iphon: Iphone) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, iphon);
  }
}
```

HERE IS THE iphon.model

```
export interface Iphone {
_id: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
email: string;
colorPrefence: string;
contact: string;
country: string;
state: string;
city: string;
zipCode: string;
transactionId: string;
__v: string;
```

}

Here is the iphone.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: "app-iphone",
templateUrl: "./iphone.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./iphone.component.css"],
providers: [IphoneService]
})
export class IphoneComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
constructor(public iphoneService: IphoneService) {}

ngOnInit() {}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
this.iphoneService.postIphone(form.value).subscribe(res => {});
```

}

I think the Error I'm getting is due to incorect binding of the model but i'm unable to figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in the way you are working out your workflow.

First you are trying to do a bind to a variable that exists in the service and not in the component. Services should not be responsible for storing view state. View state should be responsibility of the component. You would need to have a variable on your component (e.g. `selectedIphoneId`) and then you can your use that in your `[(ngModel)]`.

Also remove the assignment of the template reference `#_id=“ngModel`. If you don’t even need to use it get rid of it. You would have something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id [(ngModel)]="selectedIphoneId">
  </div>
```

Comment: thank You for the response, I tried placing ? as you suggested but its not working,
above i'll  attach the iphone.service file which i'm using'.

Comment: Ah wait why do you have the template reference #_id=“ngModel”? Get rid of that. If you need the template reference just leave #_id and nothing else

Comment: still the same error. :(, i've attached the iphone.service file above, is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I need to see your component. The service is not telling me much. Where are you assigning the data to selectedIphone?

Comment: I've attached the iphone.model above to OP

Comment: i've attached iphone.component.ts in OP

Comment: Well you are not setting the selectedIphone value anywhere. Why don’t you create a function to return your value and in the component you consume that function?

Comment: And why are you doing a bind to a variable on a service. You should have the variable on the component and assign to it.

Comment: I’ll edit my answer. Now I’ve seen some of your problems more carefully.

Comment: Yea sure thing.